# Как использовать класс в CLI

Tags: php, консоль

Есть такой вопрос. Как запускать класс из cli. Вся архитектура работает за исключением запуска из командной строки.Нашел такое решение , но не могу разобраться

```
    class Commander
{
    function __construct(array $option)
    {
        switch (key($option)){


        case "one":
            echo "one";
            break;

            case "two":
                echo "two";
                break;

            case "help"||"h":
            default:
                echo 'Help';
    }}

}
$option=getopt("o:t:h",["one:","two:","help:"]);
new Commander($option);
```

Comment: какой-то сумбур, извините. Какой класс? Как вы его используете? В чем конкретно не можете разобраться?

Comment: В кейсах вместо echo соответственно стоит new Class(); нужно из терминала запускать соответствующие кейсы (1,2 и т.д) ,Сейчас всегда выдает значение по умолчанию - help

Comment: Приведите ровно тот код, с которым у вас проблемы. И опишите, в чем конкретно проблемы. Какие ошибки? Что работает не так, как вы ожидали?

Comment: /PhpstormProjects/Project1/src $ php Commander.php
Helpyura@yura-Aspire-V5-572G ~/PhpstormProjects/Project1/src $

Comment: $ php Commander.php //запускаю без параметров выдает "help" дефолтное.
Help

Comment: Хочу так   $php Commander.php ..... как сюда передать параметры для вывода например "one" or "two"

Comment: `php Commander.php --one` пробовали?

Comment: Да, и двоеточие не нужно, если вы не хотите передавать значение параметром

Comment: php Commander.php --one все равно выдает дефолтный кейс-слово help.

Comment: Я вот только что скопипастил ваш код, запустил его `php 1.php --one aaa` и получил вывод на экран `one`

Comment: Потом я убрал двоеточие `$option=getopt("o:t:h",["one","two","help"]);`, запустил `php 1.php --one` (без передачи значения параметра) )и таки тоже получил `one`

Comment: Спасибо. Дело действительно в двоеточиях. Только интересно Вы написали что с двоеточиями тоже работает, а у меня нет. Хотя это уже не важно

Comment: Двоеточия нужны, если параметр требует передачи значения `--one aaa`. Тогда в массиве `$options` будет запись `"one" => "aaa"`. Если задать параметр как параметр с обязательным значением(двоеточие), а само значение не передать, то он отбросится и в итоговый массив не попадет